# A long-running Parse operation is being executed on the main thread?

Tags: ios, parse-platform

A long-running Parse operation is being executed on the main thread is happening on this part of code from below, i can't seem to figure out how to rid the error. Any help on how to get rid of warning.

```
PFFile *image = (PFFile *)[wallObject objectForKey:KEY_IMAGE];
UIImageView *userImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageWithData:image.getData]];
userImage.frame = CGRectMake(0, 65, wallImageView.frame.size.width, 225);
[wallImageView addSubview:userImage];
```

here is the Code Below

```
-(void)loadWallViews
{
    //Clean the scroll view
    for (id viewToRemove in [self.wallScroll subviews]){

        if ([viewToRemove isMemberOfClass:[UIView class]])
            [viewToRemove removeFromSuperview];
    }

    //For every wall element, put a view in the scroll
    int originY = 10;

    for (PFObject *wallObject in self.imageFilesArray){

        //Build the view with the image and the comments
        UIView *wallImageView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, originY, self.view.frame.size.width - 20 , 330)]; //self.view.frame.size.height
        //[[UIView appearance] setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]]; //added for problem solve

        //Add the image
        PFFile *image = (PFFile *)[wallObject objectForKey:KEY_IMAGE];

        UIImageView *userImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageWithData:image.getData]];
        userImage.frame = CGRectMake(0, 65, wallImageView.frame.size.width, 225);
        [wallImageView addSubview:userImage];

        UILabel *infoLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, wallImageView.frame.size.width,55)];
        infoLabel.text = [wallObject objectForKey:@"newsTitle"];
        infoLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:KEY_FONT size:20];
        infoLabel.textColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor];
        infoLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        infoLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
        [wallImageView addSubview:infoLabel];

        //Add the info label (User and creation date)
         NSDate *creationDate = wallObject.createdAt;
         NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
         [df setDateFormat:KEY_DATEFORMAT];

        //Add the comment
        UILabel *commentLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 50, wallImageView.frame.size.width, 12)];
        //commentLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Uploaded by: %@, %@", [wallObject objectForKey:@"NewsDetail"], [df stringFromDate:creationDate]];
        commentLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@": %@, %@", [wallObject objectForKey:@"newsDetail"], [df stringFromDate:creationDate]];
        commentLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:KEY_FONT size:10];
        commentLabel.textColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
        commentLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        [wallImageView addSubview:commentLabel];

        UILabel *readLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(self.view.frame.size.width - 71 , 50, wallImageView.frame.size.width, 12)];
        readLabel.text = @"Read more";
        readLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:KEY_FONT size:10];
        readLabel.textColor = [UIColor blueColor];
        readLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        [wallImageView addSubview:readLabel];

        UIButton *faceBtn = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(2,310, 20, 20)];
        [faceBtn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Facebook.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [faceBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(share:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [wallImageView addSubview:faceBtn];

        UIButton *twitBtn = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(32,310, 20, 20)];
        [twitBtn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Twitter.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [twitBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(share:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [wallImageView addSubview:twitBtn];

        UIButton *tumblrBtn = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(62,310, 20, 20)];
        [tumblrBtn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Tumblr.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [tumblrBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(share:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [wallImageView addSubview:tumblrBtn];

        UIButton *yourBtn = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(92,310, 20, 20)];
        [yourBtn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Flickr.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [yourBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(share:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [wallImageView addSubview:yourBtn];
     //   wallImageView = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0f, myCell.frame.size.width, 0.0f, 400.0f);
        UIView* separatorLineView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 343, self.view.frame.size.width, .8)];
        separatorLineView.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];// you can also put image here
        [wallImageView addSubview:separatorLineView];

        [self.wallScroll addSubview:wallImageView];

        originY = originY + wallImageView.frame.size.width + 1;

    }

    //Set the bounds of the scroll
    self.wallScroll.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.wallScroll.frame.size.width, originY);

    //Remove the activity indicator
    [self.activityIndicator stopAnimating];
    [self.activityIndicator removeFromSuperview];
}
```

Comment: what's the error or problem?

Comment: Peter create a symbolic breakpoint and it will lead you to offender

Answer (score 0):

You should first check to see if the data is available, and if so, use it, and if not, retrieve it.  You will still get a warning that this is a long operation (which it could be if you have a huge amount of data in your PFFile), but it is safe.  If you are only retrieving the data over the network with a block, then you will be fine.

```
// PFFile *imageFile
UIImage *image;
if ([imageFile isDataAvailable]) {
    image = [UIImage imageWithData:[imageFile getData]];
} else {
    [imageFile getDataInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSData *data, NSError *error) {
        if (error) {
            // error
        } else {
            if (data != nil) {
                image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
            }
        }
    }];
}
```

What you **don't** want to do is block on retrieving the data for your PFFile.  If the data is available in your PFFile, you can safely call getData without a block.